# Thread-safe increment/decrement with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, multithreading, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using the StackExchange.Redis package as a shared store for a multi-threaded application that will in turn be running on multiple servers simultaneously...so multi-multi-threaded ;)

One of the simplest use cases I have is that I want to keep a basic count on a series of keys (i.e. KEY1=4 KEY2=7, KEY3=13, etc). And I'll have business rules in place to enforce the max permissible value allowed for a given key. So for example, say KEY1 can only ever go as high as 5...if two threads fire at exactly the same time trying to increment it, I only want to allow one of them to succeed.

I believe I can accomplish this with a transaction by first fetching the current value and then making it condition that the value hasn't changed. Will this work as I am expecting? Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
    public void Increment(string key) {        
        IDatabase db = redisConn.GetDatabase();
        var val = db.StringGet(key);
        int maxVal = 5; 
        if (Convert.ToInt32(val) < maxVal) {
            var trans = db.CreateTransaction();
            trans.AddCondition(Condition.StringEqual(key, val));
            trans.StringIncrementAsync(key);
            trans.Execute();
        }
    }
```

PS: Love this package, it's a pleasure to work with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that should work fine. But it may be both easier and more efficient to use a Lua script via `ScriptEvaluate`.

Note: with your current code, you may want to check the response of `Execute` and "redo from start" if `false`. If a thread-race happens when moving from 2 to 3, with your current code: the update would be discarded. This wouldn't be an issue with a Lua script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marc, I'm not familiar with Lua script usage but I'll read up on it tonight. In a nutshell though, what makes it a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: @bruiseruser no need to interrupt the multiplexer to confirm the assertion, and no chance of anything failing due to data change; the script would be *something* like `if tonumber(redis.call('get', KEYS[1])) < 5 then redis.call('incr' , KEYS[1]) end`

Comment: OK I think I've got my script correct but perhaps not as efficient as it could be, here is what I wrote for Increment:  string script = string.Format("local val = tonumber(redis.call('GET', '{0}')) or 0 if val < {1} then redis.call('INCR' , '{0}') end", key, maxValue); Oddly though, when I benchmarked it it performed slower than using transactions...my test case was 100k increments and 100k decrements over 100 unique keys. Using transactions it came in at about 56 secs, with the Lua script it was 59. This is all on a single thread though, perhaps with many threads Lua wins out?